# Angular 2/4 preloader for all routes available in the application

Tags: angular, typescript, preloader

I have created a preloader service for an angular application, that displays the preloader below the top navigation. I need to show the preloader while navigating from one route to another and for all routes available within the application. As of now I have implemented preloader service within all the routes in my application. But with this approach I'll have to write the same code repeatedly for all the routes. I feel there must be a way to avoid this but I'm unable to find the exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

Provide the service on bootstrapped Angular Module, so that the service is globally accessible (Dependency Injection will provide on every component the same instance) and will exist for full lifetime of the Application (Singelton), then subscribe to '**route.events**' (is an Observable) to get notified via different events (NavigationStart, NavigationEnd etc.) when the route change.

When you need to read router configuration use '**router.config**' (is an Array).

Add service as argument on your component constructor and get what you need to display.